# Extending system.windows.application not recognized

Tags: vb.net, silverlight-4.0, extension-methods

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub LocalizationComboBox_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs)
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = TryCast(e.AddedItems(0), CultureInfo)
    Application.Current.SaveCulture()
    Application.Current.Refresh()
End Sub
```

And I'm implementing this later on:

```
Public NotInheritable Class ApplicationExtensions
Public Shared Sub Refresh(app As Application)
    DirectCast(HtmlPage.Window.GetProperty("location"), ScriptObject).Invoke("reload")
End Sub

Public NotInheritable Class ApplicationExtensions
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub
    Public Shared Sub Refresh(app As Application)
        DirectCast(HtmlPage.Window.GetProperty("location"), ScriptObject).Invoke("reload")
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub LoadCulture(app As Application)
        Try
            If IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("language") Then
                Dim language = TryCast(IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings("language"), String)
                If language IsNot Nothing Then
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo(language)
                End If
            Else
                app.SaveCulture()
            End If
        Catch
            MessageBox.Show("Please, open Silverlight settings and enable Application Storage.")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub SaveCulture(app As Application)
        Try
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings("language") = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name
        Catch
            MessageBox.Show("Please, open Silverlight settings and enable Application Storage.")
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

However, I get an error saying:

> 'SaveCulture' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Application'
>   'Refresh' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Application'
>   'SaveCulture' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Application'

Can someone help me out with this?
Now I should mention that I have a C# version of this and that has no problems.

Thanks, y'all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not following VB.NET extension method rules.  Which dictates that:

- You must write the extension methods in a Module, not a Class
- They must have the `<Extension>` attribute
- The source code file that uses them must have an `Imports` statement for the module.

And VS2010 or higher is required.  The MSDN Library article [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).